# SQL SSMS Copy Database Wizard Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, wizard

I am trying to copy a database from one server to another using the Copy Database Wizard included in SSMS. It always fails with :

> ERROR : errorCode=-1073548784 description=Executing the query "  CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CO_Summary_PostDate] ..." failed with the following error: "CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query "ResultSet" property not set correctly parameters not set correctly or connection not established correctly.`

Can anybody dissect this and help me figure out where I went wrong? Both SQL servers are SQL Server 2008 R2, I connect with SQL Server authentication, and use the SQL Server Management Object method since I require the original database to stay live in production.

The complete error log is here:

> Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
>   11/12/2013 08:46:36,CDW_FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_0,Error,0,E-MDS,CDW_FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_0,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User sa.  The last step to run was step 1 (CDW_FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_0_Step).,00:02:08,0,0,,,,0
>   11/12/2013 08:46:36,CDW_FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_0,Error,1,E-MDS,CDW_FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_0,CDW_FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_0_Step,,Executed as user: E-MDS\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.5500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:46:36 AM  Progress: 2013-11-12 08:46:37.18     Source: FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_Transfer Objects Task      Task just started the execution.: 0% complete  End Progress  Error: 2013-11-12 08:48:42.79     Code: 0x00000000     Source: FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_Transfer Objects Task      Description: ERROR : errorCode=-1073548784 description=Executing the query "  CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CO_Summary_PostDate] ..." failed with the following error: "CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query "ResultSet" property not set correctly parameters not set correctly or connection not established correctly.   helpFile= helpContext=0 idofInterfaceWithError={C81DFC5A-3B22-4DA3-BD3B-10BF861A7F9C}  StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dts.DtsTransferProvider.ExecuteTransfer()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()  End Error  Progress: 2013-11-12 08:48:42.82     Source: FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_Transfer Objects Task      Database transfer failed for 1 database(s).: 0% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2013-11-12 08:48:42.82     Source: FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_Transfer Objects Task      Transfer objects finished execution.: 100% complete  End Progress  Warning: 2013-11-12 08:48:42.82     Code: 0x80019002     Source: CDW_FEZ_FUNDEZ_E-MDS_0      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:46:36 AM  Finished: 8:48:42 AM  Elapsed:  126.142 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:02:08,0,0,,,,0

Goal is to schedule a copy of this "production" system to an analysis server for reporting periodically (once per week) so that the reporting function does not interact with the live system.

Comment: Why don't you just take a backup and restore it?

Comment: backup and restore would require the production database to go offline.

Comment: Uh, why is that? Backing up doesn't delete the database, and you can restore as a different name and to a different location.

Comment: can that be automated into a SQL agent job?  I would rather not have to manually backup/restore.

Answer (score 1):

The Copy Database wizard kept failing for me. I was also unable to export the schema and data scripts as the database was too large. Additionally I was also unable to do a backup to my local machine since the server was on a hosted environment and did not have access. This doesn't set any auto Identity columns though. My solution was:

1. Create the a new blank local database.
2. Use the Import wizard, right click on database. Tasks->Import Data
3. Use the Sql Server Native Client and set the Source and Destination. This will import the tables / data but will not import the indexes / constraints.
4. Use the scripts below to get the indexes / constraints and foreign key from your source and run them on your local database. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3443/script-all-primary-keys-unique-constraints-and-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database-using-tsql/

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CO_Summary_PostDate] ...
```

failed with the following error:

> CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'.

You have an indexed view in you database. The wizard tries to recreate the index but your session doesn't have the proper settings. Try to remove this object from the objects copied by the wizard and recreate the view and its index manually afterwards.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there is not a lot of options in the wizard. I'm not familiar with the copy database task (it is an Integration Services tasks that the wizard calls in the background), I don' t know if it sets the ansi_padding option to off. Can you first check if the destination database has the ANSI_PADDING option set to ON 

`SELECT name, is_ansi_padding_on
FROM sys.databases` and if not, can you set it to ON to see if it changes anything ?